# Getting a UDP Server in Java to work so others can connect from outside of my network

Tags: java, sockets

I've just recently been trying to setup a server that uses UDP in Java. So far I've managed to compile my code and I've gotten a response from the server when I specified localhost as the Inetaddress. The next thing I wanted to try was to setup the server so that it uses my public IP address and as a result others can connect who are not in my network. Unfortunately I keep on getting a "Cannot assign requested address: cannot bind" error. I'm pretty sure that I've correctly forwarded the port I specified inside of my program(I've tried other ports aswell, no success). 
Maybe somebody can look into my code and see if there is something that causes this issues :)
I've attached pictures with all the relevant classes.
Thanks in advance and please don't go hard on me, Im still pretty much a beginner.

Gameserver:
http://puu.sh/kFwzu/e18ed0feb3.png

Gameclient:
http://puu.sh/kFu4S/5e0616dfc3.png + 
puu.sh/kFwDb/5f784bddfe.png

Game(Class where the server is initialized):
 puu.sh/kFwnS/dcd9ca9986.png

I only included relevant parts of the code.
The error happens in the GameServer's constructor where I initialze the socket :
this.socket = new DatagramSocket(laddr);

Error name:
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind

Comment: Ports < 1024 are privileged ports on linux (and other)  systems. The java process might have insufficient rights. What OS is in use? Did you try some net example code that has proven its correctness? Providing the code as image is suboptimal.

Comment: Hey there! Ive tried different ports that are above 1024 and it did not solve my issue. I am using Windows 10 :P. Oh and yes I was able to send packets when i specified the IP address to be localhost, everything was working perfectly fine.